# Type Aliases for Constraints don't share the same variable binding behavior as Contexts

Tags: haskell, constraints, type-families, type-variables

I've been playing with `-XConstraintKinds` to help alleviate excessively verbose contexts, and have found an interesting inconsistency in terms of variable binding:

```
{-# LANGUAGE
    TypeFamilies
  , ConstraintKinds
  , FlexibleContexts
  #-}

-- works
foo :: ( callTree ~ SomeTypeFunc output
       , OtherTypeFunc input ~ callTree
       ) => input -> output


type FooCtx input output =
  ( callTree ~ SomeTypeFunc output
  , OtherTypeFunc input ~ callTree
  )

-- doesn't work
foo' :: FooCtx input output =>
        input -> output
```

Is there a work-around for this, other than bringing `callTree` to the top-level scope?

Comment: What happens if you make `callTree` an argument to `FooCtx`?

Comment: If you ask for the type of `foo` you'll see it is `SomeTypeFunc o ~ OtherTypeFunc i => i-> o`. References to `callTree` are removed by simplification. In fact, if your `foo` type *couldn't* be simplified to get rid of `callTree`, GHC would likely complain about amiguous types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no real inconsistency, it's just that

1. Free type variables in a type signature have `forall` quantifiers automatically added, so the first case is really equivalent to

   ```
   foo :: forall callTree output input. ( callTree ~ SomeTypeFunc output
          , OtherTypeFunc input ~ callTree
          ) => input -> output
   ```
2. All free type variables on the right side of a `type` declaration must be parameters, you cannot have any that are not in scope.

This is not specific to constraint kinds, except for the unfortunate fact that you cannot apply `forall` quantifiers directly to a constraint, which means I don't know a *general* workaround to make such a constraint type declaration work.

In your particular example, `( OtherTypeFunc input ~ SomeTypeFunc output )` should be equivalent, but I assume you're really interested in a more complicated example where such a rewriting doesn't work.

I can think of a different kind of workaround that changes the parameters to the type declaration in a different way, by including the value on the right side of the constraint:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, ConstraintKinds, FlexibleContexts, RankNTypes #-}

type family OtherTypeFunc a
type family SomeTypeFunc a

type FooCtx input output value =
  forall callTree. ( callTree ~ SomeTypeFunc output
  , OtherTypeFunc input ~ callTree
  ) => value

-- This now works
foo' :: FooCtx input output ( input -> output )

foo' = undefined
```

Comment: Huh. I thought that `forall` was implicit for some reason. Oops.

Comment: Wait a minute ... can that quantified constraint be satisfied?

Comment: @dfeuer I should think so, note that now the `forall` scopes over the `=> value` part too, so it just says that *if* `callTree` is equal to both of the other types, then you have a `value`. As you noted, if you ask for `:t foo'`, `callTree` gets removed; this happens with this version as well.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice you scrapped the constraint type synonym in favor of a normal one. Whoops!

Comment: Note that the type of `foo'` is *still* `OtherTypeFunc input ~ SomeTypeFunc output => input -> output`. I believe that this trick only works when the extra type variable is eliminated by simplification.